# Symfony2: display DB error in the form

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, message

I have a form with regular validation. In some cases, it may happen that the form validation says "ok, you can save", but because of constraints in the DB, the save operation fails.

Currently, in this case, this redirects the user to an error page. I'd like to catch the error (this is OK) and display the exception message in the form, like any other form error.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a validator on you entity like the "UniqueEntity" validator for the unique constraint:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html

Note that Doctrine annotations are only used for the database and are not used with form validators, so you have to add both.